# Dump data from a Nutch crawl into multiple warc files

Tags: web-crawler, nutch, warc

I have crawled a list of websites using Nutch 1.12. I can dump the crawl data into separate HTML files by using:

```
./bin/nutch dump -segment crawl/segments/ -o outputDir nameOfDir
```

And into a single WARC file by using:

```
./bin/nutch warc crawl/warcs crawl/segment/nameOfSegment
```

But how can I dump the collected data into multiple WARC files, one for each webpage crawled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a few attempts, I managed to find out that

```
./bin/nutch commoncrawldump -outputDir nameOfOutputDir -segment crawl/segments/segmentDir -warc
```

does exactly what I needed: a full dump of the segment into individual WARC files!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit wasteful to have one WARC per doc but here you go :
you could specify a low value for 'warc.output.segment.size' so that the files get rotated every time a new document is written. WarcExporter uses [https://github.com/ept/warc-hadoop] under the bonnet, the config is used there.

Comment: Is the same possible without the use of Hadoop?